# Java Invert Image Alpha

Tags: java, image, alpha-transparency

I have a situation where I need to invert the alpha channel of a `VolatileImage`

My current implementation is the obvious, but very slow;

```
public BufferedImage invertImage(VolatileImage v) {
    BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Graphics g = b.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(v, 0, 0, null);
    for(int i = 0; i < b.getWidth(); i++) {
        for(int(j = 0; j < b.getHeight(); j++) {
            Color c = new Color(b.getRGB(i, j, true));
            c = new Color(c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), 255 - c.getAlpha());
            b.setRGB(i, j, c.getRGB());
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

This works fine, but is painfully slow. I have large images and need this to be fast. I have messed around with the `AlphaComposite` but to no avail - this is not really a composting problem as far as I understand.

Given that `255 - x` is equivalent to `x & 0xff` for `0 <= x < 256`, can I not do an en-masse XOR over the alpha channel somehow?

Comment: Maybe wrap in an `IntBuffer` and operate on each `int`?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of googleing, I came across `DataBuffer` classes being used as maps into `BufferedImages`:

```
DataBufferByte buf = (DataBufferByte)b.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
byte[] values = buf.getData();
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i += 4) values[i] = (byte)(values[i] ^ 0xff);
```

This inverts the values of the `BufferedImage` (you do not need to draw it back over, altering the array values alters the buffered image itself).

My tests show this method is about 20 times faster than jazzbassrob's improvement, which was about 1.5 times faster than my original method.

Comment: Why the `for` loop skip 3 items each loop? (`i += 4`)

Comment: Ok, i understand now. in 32-bit images, every 4 bytes represent 1-red 2-green 3-blue 4-alpha. so we need to change only the alpha byte

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to speed it up by avoiding all the getters and the constructor inside the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < b.getWidth(); i++) {
    for(int(j = 0; j < b.getHeight(); j++) {
        b.setRGB(b.getRGB(i, j) ^ 0xFF000000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced the loop contents with `b.setRGB(i, j, b.getRGB(i, j) ^ 0xff000000);` but it is still very slow. Is is not possible to apply this XOR to an array of RGB values? or even the whole image at once?

Comment: @lynks I've just been looking at the `getAlphaRaster` method... I'm not putting it as an answer because I'm not sure, but there is a possibility that will be relevant

Comment: Some combination of `int[] BufferedImage.getRGB()` and `WritableRaster.setPixels()` maybe. Just got to avoid the full-pixel loop somehow.

Comment: That's what I was wondering.  Incidentally, how big/how much time are we talking?

Comment: Around 800x600, and it should really be doing 30 or so per second.